# Cloud composer detect container finished running

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am using the bash operator in order to schedule a container to run on a compute instance.

```
gcloud beta compute instances create-with-container airflow-vm --zone us-central1-a --container-image gcr.io/cloud-marketplace/google/image-which-does-calculations:1.0
```

The container automatically starts a process to do some calculations. How Can I detect that the process has completed it's calculations?

Comment: I'd probably have my GCE instance write to GCS and use the GCS Sensor http://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/airflow/contrib/sensors/gcs_sensor.html

Comment: then pub/sub is also an option. But how do I handle a failure?

Comment: You're right. Ideally there would be a GCE instance sensor. You could put a write to pub/sub or gcs in the shutdown script for the instance, but that leaves the door open to flakiness. Combined with a timeout on the sensor, it should get you close.